# iPhone X - How are we supposed to handle the space above table section headers? It's showing through the content

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, iphone-x

I have a tableview with multiple sections and section headers for each section. As you know, section header moves with the tableview. So if there are more than one sections, the current section's header sticks to the top of the tableview while the content of that section scrolls under the header.

I am trying to figure out on how it's supposed to get adapted for the iPhone X as the space above the header is showing through the content as you notice in this screenshot. I looked at the Apple view on how to adapt for the iPhone X notch but all their examples had a search bar view on top so they never really faced this issue.

[image]

Comment: If application is displaying status bar. This problem will resolved by default.

Comment: @rptwsthi Not really, this problem will only be solved if I show a useless navigation bar at the top which stays stuck. But that basically means I am wasting screen space.

Comment: You could show status bar.

Comment: Haven't played with UIKit in a while, but isn't there a safe area constraint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing.

I added a new `UIView` (`notchFIxView`) with UIVisualEffectView inside. I placed it at the very top of the view controller. This is the topmost view outside all the tableview. I pinned the top, left and right constraints to the superview (NOT the safe area).

I pinned the bottom of this view to the top of the Safe Area.

I added `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol to the interface and following macros for iPhoneX detection:

```
#define IS_IPHONE (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
#define SCREEN_WIDTH ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width)
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)
#define SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH (MAX(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
#define IS_IPHONE_X (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 812.0)
```

I added a `BOOL checkIfNotch;` variable to my interface and initialize it in the viewDidLoad:

```
checkIfNotch = IS_IPHONE_X;
```

Then the final showing/hiding of the `notchFIxView` happens as follows:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    if (checkIfNotch) {
        static CGFloat lastY = 0;

        CGFloat currentY = scrollView.contentOffset.y;

        if ((lastY <= tableheaderviewHeight) && (currentY > tableheaderviewHeight)) {
            NSLog(@" ******* Header view just disappeared");

            self.notchFIxView.hidden=NO;
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
                self.notchFIxView.alpha=1;
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

            }];

        }

        if ((lastY > tableheaderviewHeight) && (currentY <= tableheaderviewHeight)) {
            NSLog(@" ******* Header view just appeared");

            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
                self.notchFIxView.alpha=0;
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                self.notchFIxView.hidden=YES;
            }];
        }

        lastY = currentY;
    }
}
```

After this, it looks much nicer:

[image]

Comment: Atrocious. How it _looks_ is not the point. There is a right way to do this, it's simple, it requires no code at all, and yet you're not willing to do it.

Comment: @matt Sorry, I do not understand what's wrong in my way? How does your answer look when the tableview is not scrolled at all? When it's at the very top? Can you share a screenshot of that?

Comment: What's wrong with your "way" is that it's just a bunch of ad-hoc hacky twiddling. There is a simple right way that requires no code, and is what Apple intends for you to do — that is why they gave you the Safe Area. So why not do it?

Comment: The way you are referring to as "right" if I am understanding correctly is to make the tableview top start at the safe area instead of the superview top. If I do that, then the entire area around the notch is black which is something Apple discourages in their guidelines. Or am I still misunderstanding your way?

Comment: You're already violating the guidelines in having a table view controller without a navigation bar. You'll notice that none of Apple's apps does that.

Comment: Nowhere in their design guidelines do they say that they discourage hiding the navigation bar. Navigation bar would make sense if I actually had any navigation stack. My app doesn't. For a game, it doesn't make sense to show the status bar either. However for the notch they say "Don't attempt to hide the device's rounded corners, sensor housing, or indicator for accessing the Home screen by placing black bars at the top and bottom of the screen. "

Answer (score 1):

> as the space above the header is showing through the content as you notice in this screenshot

Distinguish two things: the main view, which stretches up behind the notch, and the table view. Pin the top of the table view to the top of the safe area. On the iPhone X, and *only* on the iPhone X, the top of the safe area will be way down from the top of the main view, and the bottom of the safe area will be up from the bottom of the main view, keeping your table view from getting up behind the notch or down behind the indicator.

In this screen shot, there are several cells scrolled above the A header, but you don't see them. And the bottom of the table view stays clear of the virtual home indicator.

[image]

It's just a matter of giving the table view controller a parent view controller with a black background. You can do that in code, or you can configure it entirely without code in the storyboard.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the screenshot. The view which you see behind the section header is the tableview cell which has been scrolled up. "Ice" is one of the cells, just like "Beach", "Galaxy" etc. There is no main view, just a table view with section headers.

Comment: I think you misunderstand my answer. I tell you that the solution is you _need_ two views, a table view but a main view behind it.

Comment: How does your answer look when the tableview is not scrolled at all? When it's at the very top. Can you share a screenshot of that?

Comment: It looks just the same, but the top cell is Alabama; then Alaska, then Arizona (those are all scrolled above the header in the screen shot).

Comment: What I am looking for is that are you hiding the entire notch area in black?

Comment: I am not "hiding" anything. On the contrary, everything is exposed. That is the view controller's main view. It is black. Please take a deep breath and try to _read_ my answer. It explains completely.

Comment: I have read your answer 3 times. my view controller background is not black, it sort of looks dark because the simulator I am using doesn't blur correctly. The background is a UIVisualEffectView which shows through a blur of the thing behind. If I make the tableview start at the safe area instead of the superview, then it looks tacky at the top as the area around the notch is just blur see through and when scrolling, the tableview content disappears even before getting to the edge of the screen. That looks tacky.

Comment: Same with the section headers I have - they are actually not black, they are blurred background which simulator screenshot looks black.

Comment: I don't see what that has to do with anything. But okay, I've said what I had to say.

Comment: @NicholasFarmer Let's stick to your new question please.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested then you can have a look at this github page which gives you the ability to solve this notch issue:

https://github.com/HarshilShah/NotchKit

Comment: From that page: "P.S.: This was made mostly as a joke while I was debating different ways to handle the iPhone X.

Apple's updated Human Interface Guidelines for the iPhone X explicitly call this out:

Don't mask or call special attention to key display features. Don't attempt to hide the device's rounded corners, sensor housing, or indicator for accessing the Home screen by placing black bars at the top and bottom of the screen. 
I'm not sure if violating the HIG is often used as grounds for a rejection, however I wouldn't bet either way."