# iPhone X - space above safe area issue

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, storyboard

This question does already poses the exact same issue that I'm having:
[iPhone X - How are we supposed to handle the space above table section headers? It's showing through the content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46418229/iphone-x-how-are-we-supposed-to-handle-the-space-above-table-section-headers)

I've got a UICollectionView with a header at the top which holds a few buttons.
When the UICollectionView scrolls up, so it goes under the header and then shows through in the space above the header.

Unfortunately I'm not quite following the answer given by Matt, how does one:
"It's just a matter of giving the table view controller a parent view controller with a black background. You can do that in code, or you can configure it entirely without code in the storyboard."

I would of contacted Matt directly but there isn't an option for this.

EDIT:
Screenshot of my storyboard, would greatly appreciate advice on what I need to do (please talk as if you would to a dog or small child'(!)
[image]

Comment: But see my comments on the OP's own answer. The _right_ way to do this is to wrap your collection view controller in a navigation controller. The navigation bar hides the cells and stretches up behind the "notch". If you can't do that, please edit the question to describe your view / view controller hierarchy.

Comment: Sorry Matt, I think I'm having some kind of mental block. What exactly do you mean by 'wrap your collection view controller in a navigation controller'. I'm just not following.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, Apple really doesn't support a table view controller or collection view controller that isn't a child view controller of some surrounding view controller. It could be a custom parent view controller (as in @AamirR's answer), but the most common approach is to put it inside a navigation interface (a UINavigationController). Now the navigation bar occupies the top of the screen. It automatically grows up behind the "notch" in the iPhone X. It covers the cells as they go above the header.

If you look at Apple's apps, they *all* work like that. For example, look at the Moments view in the Photos app, or the Month view in the Calendar app. They all have a navigation bar at the top.

So, embed your Subject View Controller in a Navigation Controller.

iPhone 5:

[image]

iPhone X:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, can this be done through storyboard alone or programmatically as per AamirR advice?

Comment: Storyboard is fine. Just select the view controller and choose from the Embed menu. You'll have to hook the segues back up, that's all.

Comment: Editor -> Embed In is the menu you want.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a parent view controller for `UICollectionViewController` and add `SubjectViewController` as a child of that parent, like so:

```
class SubjectParentViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = .gray

        // Add collection view as a child view controller
        let collectionViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SubjectVC")
        collectionViewController.willMove(toParentViewController: self)
        self.addChildViewController(collectionViewController)

        let collectionView: UIView = collectionViewController.view
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

        // add auto-layout constraints to layout guides
        var guide: UILayoutGuide!

        guide = self.view.layoutMarginsGuide
        collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

        guide = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        collectionView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToSystemSpacingBelow(guide.topAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true
        collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToSystemSpacingBelow(guide.bottomAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true
    }

}
```

Edit your storyboard with these 2 steps:

1. Create a view controller, and set its class to be above custom class `SubjectParentViewController`
2. Move all segues from `SubjectViewController` to `SubjectParentViewController`

Finally, create a File `SubjectParentViewController.swift` and paste the class

This sets `UITableViewController/UICollectionViewController`'s view aligned to layout margins and safe-area guides:

[image]